# Creating new image from cropped image

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, graphic

I'm currently trying to crop an image, and then save the new image. I have the original image, the x and y co-ordinates of where on that image I want the cropping to being, and the width and height of the new cropped image.

Here is my code:

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = new Bitmap(filePath);
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
g.DrawImage(originalBitmap, x, y, width, height);
newImage.Save(newFilePath);
```

But when the image is acutally saved, it's a small image of the correct height and width, but is completely empty.

I'm sure I'm just missing a trick here, or completely misunderstanding something (or both!), so any help at all would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using Clone function of Bitmap:

```
Bitmap newImage = originalBitmap.Clone(new RectangleF(x, y, width, height),  
                                       System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
newImage.Save(newFilePath);
```

Comment: You are a genius, I shall dedicate one of my pints of Guinness to you this evening! Thanks! :-)

Comment: can you send it to me next time ;)